# Triggered Sends Tracking in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

We are using Triggered Sends to send emails to Contacts. Emails are going from Marketing Cloud.

Emails are going successfully and I can see all the tracking in Marketing Cloud but I **am not able to** view those sends on the Contact Record in Salesforce. Nothing is appearing under the 'Email Send' related list.

Is it a desired behavior or there is some configuration that I am missing? In the worst case, how can track these sends from withing Salesforce?

Comment: Any suggestions experts?

Comment: There is a delay on the tracking data that goes back to SFDC.  Up to an hour.  Do you see the tracking data under the Triggered Sends section in SFDC?  To get to this section go to the Marketing Cloud tab and click the triggered sends link in the top right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can also check Triggered Send Email Status and other details like fromAddress, ToAddress, Email Subject, status  via REST API.

**Endpoint**:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageSends/key:{Email External Key}

**Header**:
content-Type: application/json,
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}

**Request Type:** GET

2. You can get more details for tracking by using below API.

**Endpoint**:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageSends/{id}/summary

**Header**:
content-Type: application/json,
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}

**Request Type**: GET

For more Details, you can refer below API.

**Endpoint**:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/rest

**Header**:
content-Type: application/json,
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}

**Request Type**: GET